# Fast functional sequential collection

Tags: list, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for a sequential collection data structure (i.e. something that can be viewed as a list) for which:

1. The basic splicing operations (add or remove elements anywhere in the list) are amortized O(log N) or better (so an array doesn't qualify, because it's only fast to add or remove elements at the end).
2. This is true even if used functionally, i.e. the operations are nondestructive (so a doubly linked list doesn't qualify because for nondestructive operation you have to copy the entire list; the same is true of a rope, from what I can see).

Is there any data structure that meets these criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want a balanced binary tree. They come in purely functional flavors and are good for not only sorted maps but sequences also.

The adaptation required is to map sequence indexes to values. To avoid an expensive renumbering on mid-sequence operations, don't represent the keys directly; instead, have each node store the total number of nodes in its left subtree. During a downward traversal, maintain the index of the current node by adding the count whenever the traversal goes right.